# Ajax - onload attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onload

How is possible to bring data from server `onload` data from server?
I have something like this, and it's not working:
JS:

```
function getItems(){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("ask", "MainView");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getItems.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result){
      var result=trim(result);
      $("#PageWrap").html(result);
    }
  });
}
function getItemsOnLoad(){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("ask", "OnLoad");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getItemsOnload.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result){
      var result=trim(result);
      $("#onloadInfoID").html(result);
    }
  });  
}
```

PHP getItems.php:

```
echo <table onload="getItemsOnLoad()"><tr>some info</tr></table>;
```

Comment: Put this function on below of your page and call it like this 
`var aa=getItemsOnLoad();` no need to call it from table or body anything

Comment: function dont call getItemsOnLoad(); every time, dont know why.

Comment: Dude it's alot of code, and i found the answer, it's below ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getItems(){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("menuItem", menuItem);
  formData.append("ask", "MainView");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getItems.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result){
      var result=trim(result);
      $("#PageWrap").html(result);
    }
  }).done(function() {
    formData.append("ask", "OnLoad");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getItemsOnload.php",
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(result){
        var result=trim(result);
        $("#onloadInfoID").html(result);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

That was it, .done(). Change only js file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, why you can't make it in `ready`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getItemsOnLoad();
});
```

Comment: That would work, only in my case it won't. `Onload` i bring small part of data, and i have to bring much more data hidden. I need to bring big part of data after(`onload`) i bring small part of data. Dont know if `ready` on `ready` is possible.

Answer (score -1):

try this on `<body>` tag

```
<body onload="getItemsOnLoad()">
```

Comment: this will bring data from server at the same time with `onload="getItems()"`